# Why don't I have to commit after git merge

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a repo master and I do with file1.txt and file2.txt

```
git checkout -b fix1
```

I then change file1.txt

and I do a

```
git commit -a
```

then I do  a

```
git checkout master
```

then I do a

```
git checkout -b fix2
```

I then change file2.txt

and I do a

```
git commit -a
```

then `git checkout master`
then a

```
git merge fix1
git marge fix2
```

but if I do a

```
 commit -a
```

I get

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`git merge` commits automatically. If you don't want to commit add the `--no-commit` argument:

> ```
>   --commit, --no-commit
>       Perform the merge and commit the result. This option can be used to override --no-commit.
>
>       With --no-commit perform the merge but pretend the merge failed and do not autocommit, to give the user
>       a chance to inspect and further tweak the merge result before committing.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

If the merge succeeds without conflict, git will automatically commit it (which you should be able to verify by simply checking `git log`).

[The documentation notes](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) (emphasis added):

> ... "git merge topic" will replay the changes made on the topic branch since it diverged from master (i.e., E) until its current commit (C) on top of master, **and record the result in a new commit** along with the names of the two parent commits and a log message from the user describing the changes

If you want to avoid this, use the `--no-commit` flag:

```
git merge --no-commit fix1
```

Answer (score 1):

The merged files, which don't have conflicts are already merged. You can directly push your merged files.